# Prohibit Apple Anonymous Email Usage for Users

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Haven't found this yet on Apple documentation. Is there a way to prohibit apple anon email use in auth?  For my app requirements, anon emails is impossible.

Comment: Impossible. Apple will never allow something like that.

Comment: The issue for me is that I need users to share their contact info....with verifying the email.  I'll have to have users manually provide email, and then manually verify...just extra steps....when the email is right there. Not looking to do this without users knowledge....just an app toggle that App requires actual email for user-user sharing.

Comment: again, if the user don't want to share their real email and be anon... there's nothing you can do. Apple will forward any email you send to that fake email and will reach the correct one, but it will be impossible for you to know the real email.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently not, you should stand by apple rules. Anyways if you need to comunicate with the anonymous mail,

> Apple generates a proxy email address to forward email to the user’s private email address.

So this should be fine anyways.

Comment: Not trying to circumvent rules. Just a basic user requirement within the app that users can see and email each other.  Anon emails must have registered senders, which will be impossible.